# Why wrapper object is eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java

This question is taken from SCJP. We need to find Objects which are eligible for garbage collecrtion. The answer says c3 and short story. I need to know , why its short story eligible for GC. This is actually an instance variable. Does it mean, if i don't use my instance variables they are eligible for Garbage Collection?

Actual Answer as per book is : Only one CardBoard object (c1) is eligible, but it has an associated Short wrapper object that is also eligible. So "two" objects are eligible.

```
class CardBoard {
    Short story = 200;
    CardBoard go(CardBoard cb) {
      cb = null;
      return cb;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();
      CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
      CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2);
      c1 = null;
      // do Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen to the `Short` instance once the enclosing `CardBoard` instance is GCed?

Comment: Yaa thats what i am thinking what will happen to short if C1 is garbaged?

Answer (score 3):

It all comes down to what the garbage collector considers "reachable". Basically, it starts at the so called garbage collection roots (the local variables in an executing thread are an example of such roots), and follows all references to other objects. After having visited all objects it can reach by traversing all these references, there are a few left which are no longer reachable, meaning no matter how hard you try, you'll never use these objects again, so they can be safely thrown away (or collected as garbage).

Although `c1` references its `story` object, there is no way to reach either one, so they're both eligible.

`c3` never references an object, the example is intended to confuse, but `go()` always returns the null reference and no object instance is ever created for `c3`, and it's also not hanging on to either object referenced by `c1` or `c2` (although the later is irrelevant for this case, since it's still referenced by the `c2` variable).

Comment: BUT WHY IT IS SAYING "associated Short wrapper object that is also eligible" ?? WHAT THAT MEAN?

Comment: @user2985842; no need to shout. It means that the object referenced by the variable `c1` is in turn referencing an object of type `Short` (called wrapper object, as it's only wrapping a primitive value and has no other purpose than allow it to be used as an object), and although it is referenced, it is no longer reachable, and thus eligible for garbage collection. If it's the "associated" part that's tripping you up, you need to have another look at objects and classes, each `CardBoard` object instance have (by the class definition) a reference to a `Short` object via the field `story`.

Comment: Sorry 4r shout...I didn't mean that...I got ure answer...thanks

Answer (score 1):

If nothing refers to `c1` then the `Short story = 200;` field (belonging to the `c1` instance) is also eligible for collection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer doesn't say `c3` it says `c1` and thus the `Short story` it contains.  This is due to the line

```
c1 = null;
```

At this point the object which was referenced by `c1` can be GCed and thus any object it refers to.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: c3 never was anything but null.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But there's no object that's becoming unreferenced. Garbage collection happens on instances, not the variables that (no longer) contain them.

Comment: @roe Good catch, you're right. It was never instantiated.

Comment: Technically it is implementation dependent - `story` may be cached in which case `c1.story == c2.story` and only `c1` is eligible! ;-)